# Saving image in chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am new to javascript. How can I save image type of data using chrome.storage.sync.set() in javascript? And how to retrieve as well?

I have created a context menu item "xyz" and how to save image by clicking on "xyz" menu item?

```js
var contextMenuItem = {     "id": "xyz",    "title": "xyz",     "contexts": ["image"] };
chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem); 

function clickData() { 
if(info.menuItemId == "xyz")    { 
//Here I have to save the clicked image(small in size - so I'm using chrome.storage)
//chrome.storage.local.set({ src: img.src });   
}
}

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(clickData);
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: You can only save primitive types to local storage and it has limited size which is unlikely to be enough for an image (unless it is a very small one). Consider saving a link to the image instead

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Can we get link of image on directly clicking the context menu item?

Comment: You should be able to get the source of the image, how exactly to go about it will depend on the DOM structure. If not a secret what are you trying to do? What is the goal behind saving images to local storage?